# Displaying label control depending on condition

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have three pages on my site. Page 1 is home page. When user visits the site, i display label control to user in Page 1. When the same user goes to page 2 , 3 and returns back to page 1, i do not want the label to show again. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write a cookie to the client on page 2 then check for its existence upon loading page 1.  If they have the cookie don't show the label.  There is a pretty good jquery cookie plugin [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Request.UrlReferrer property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=1673